# Using and populating (real) DBRef arrays with Mongoose / mongoose-dbref

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, data-modeling

Mongoose doesn't appear to support Mongo DBRefs. Apparently they released "DBRef" support but it was actually just plain references (no ability to reference documents from different collections). I've finally managed to craft a schema that allows me to hold an array of ObjectID references and populate them, which is great for certain parts of my schema, but it would be extremely convenient if I could use proper DBRefs to create an array that lets me refer to documents from a number of collections.

Luckily(?) there's a module that can monkey patch DBRef support into mongoose: https://github.com/goulash1971/mongoose-dbref

Unluckily, I can't make any sense of the documents. The best I can tell is that there is no ability to use DBRefs in an array (there is a 'fetch' method to dereference, but it takes a single dbref); 'populate' doesn't seem to be patched to fill in DBRefs, and I can't tell how I'm supposed to *assign* a DBRef given a source document [collection.items.push(?????)].

From the internet, it appears that I can assign an object of the form { $id: document._id, $ref: 'Collection' } -- when logging the result, it appears to have "taken" as a DBRef data type, but I am unsure if this is correct since I cannot seem to do anything useful with it (turn the ref back into a document).

What I really want is a way to represent an ordered list of items from multiple collections; any solution to this is fine by me, but so far DBRefs are the best I've got. Help?

Comment: DBRefs aren't useful in Mongoose. They add no value as they are just meta-data about the identifier that is associated with them. MongoDB doesn't use them in any meaningful way.

Comment: You might want to consider splitting data into multiple arrays if possible and relying on `ref` so you could use `populate`.

Comment: I did consider that, but it makes ordering difficult. I have, essentially, blocks of content that I need to store. Some of the blocks have a different structure than others, and so they have their own schema. I discovered that you can have multiple models in a single collection in Mongoose, but I can't use the collection as a ref, only a model :(

Comment: Why did you pick MongoDb?

Comment: It was what the base system I am using used. It would be more work to rip it out than to figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DBRef ([as explained in detail here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/)) is a tuple containing the ObjectId, collection name, and possibly the database container name of a referenced object in another collection.

Internally in the MongoDB server these serve no purpose and are just data within a document. The point is for use in some drivers and ODM implementations to allow for some sort of automatic expansion by issuing additional queries to the server in order to have the data that is elsewhere appear to be an ordinary sub-document part of the referencing document. This can be automatic or a lazy load depending on the implementation, but is always done over the wire and processed on the client side. The server will do nothing to traverse or join this data.

Additionally, MongoDB collections are schemaless, so there is nothing as in the relational sense that says all documents in a collection have to have the same structure.

In the case of Mongoose, there are built in functions to do this sort of loading for you as a convenience, and while not strictly a DBRef and utilizing documents with a different schema in the same collection is the same means as storing the documents external to the referencing document.

It is important to consider the data access patterns of your application and not to simply opt for the same sort of relational design you are used to. Keeping in mind that you are only ever reading from one collection at a time, it is most desirable to get at the data you need in a single read or write, without multiple operations over the wire, which will slow things down considerably.

In short, you should always consider embedding sub-documents first, and then use external references any your best supported form only when you absolutely have to. Your application users will thank you in the end.

Comment: I've progressed on this problem since I posted, but I thank you for the clear explanation of what DBRefs actually are. You're correct in assuming that I didn't realize they were nothing special on Mongo's end. My first working implementation did more or less what you said here: take advantage of the schemaless nature of things. It doesn't solve all my problems, but I got some more help from a kind fellow on IRC, so between that and this, I am pretty set to go :)

Comment: So what, you then embed the whole user document as a subdocument in all the users data? And when the user changes something? You have to write an own updatescript replacing all user subdocuments and having massive redundant data? I dont know any usecase where i would want that, ever.